# How to Change last entered value in a hash table

Tags: powershell, hashtable

```
$ord=$values |ForEach-Object{"'$_',"}     #returns all values
Write-Host "oders list:"$ord
```

values are in hash table
My script return's the output as

```
'312312','123123','213123',
```

But I do not want that last value to have that "," in it '213123',

Is because while querying if it as "," at the end of values it throws an error

```
select * from table('312312','123123','213123',)--wrong value
select * from table('312312','123123','213123')-correct value
```

I have tried using `-replace` but it affects all the value.
If it can be solved by Endswith or TrimEnd??..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `-join` method to *join* the string:

```
$ord= ($values | ForEach-Object{"'$_'"}) -join ','
```

Comment: Values are in hashtable ,Martin

Answer (score 0):

I made a slight change as Martin mentioned and it worked.

But the operator didn't work just after
ForEach-Object

it worked when it was like 
$ord -join ','

$ord=$values | ForEach-Object{"'$_'"}
$ord -join ','